# How to store records ascending based on timestamp?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nosql

I have the following schema from my db

```
var transactionsHistorySchema = new schema({
    pointsAtThisMomentCustomer: Number, 
    notes: String,
    rate: {
        value: Number,
        notes: String,
        date: Number,
        isRated: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Number, default: new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get the first transaction after specific date `startDate`

What I tried

```
db.TransactionsHistory.findOne({
    createdAt: { $gte: info.startDate }
}).sort({ "createdAt": 1 }).exec(function (err, objStart) {
})
```

But the problem with my code is that it needs to sort the retrieved records every time, because mongoose doesn't store the records ascending.

How can I make mongoose store the records ascending based on `createAt` attribute

Comment: You cannot do that, it's not a thing. You have to sort them.

Comment: what if the result contain 500 records and 1000 users are calling the same API. 
so we will have 1000 sorting process, each of 500 records. isn't that a big waste of server resources and time?

Comment: @MahmoudSaeed this is the database responsibility to store and manage the data. You have no power on that. If you want to avoid access the database 1000 times, you can add a caching system.

Comment: @MahmoudSaeed that is done by the database server internally; it's already optimized.